# Get image uploader

Tags: php, wikipedia-api

I'm using Wikipedia's API to get images from some values.

This is the link - https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=pageimages&titles=Yankee_Stadium&pithumbsize=500

As you'll see, it returns some json data, but without the person who upload it (I need to put some credit in my website).

Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean, something like this: https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:Le_Yankee_Stadium.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url||user

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prop=imageinfo` from:

[API:Imageinfo](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Imageinfo)

https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:Le_Yankee_Stadium.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url||user